# How to convert times in UTC to a corresponding Date and time in UTC using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of time in UTC as follows:

```
Array = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60,66,72,78,84,90,96,102,108,114,120,126]
```

I want corresponding date and time in string format.

For example: If starting date(say) is `28-04-2019`, the date and time for `0, 6, 12, 18` will be `28-04-2019:0, 28-04-2019:6,28-04-2019:12 and 28-04-2019:18`. And similarly for `24, 30,36 and 42` should be `29-04-2019:00, 29-04-2019:06, 29-04-2019:12, 30-04-2019:18` and so on.

Comment: You said you've an array of time but are just numbers. First and second example has nearly similar output. something is not right.. and what have you tried? Why email?

Comment: I always though a UTC time had a Z on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are new to SO, I'm cutting you some slack.  But To start I would like to point out a couple of issues with your question and what you have shown.

1. First as someone already pointed out Array is not an Array it is a list.  When presenting information in future try to be specific and accurate.
2. While not explicitly stated, the list is expressed as hours offset from the start date.  You should always carefully define your variables.
3. Your start date seems to be a string expressing a date inn the form of mm-dd-yyyy.  Again, always try to be explicit in defining variables.
4. You don't specify the form of desired output.  Options include a datetime compatible timestamp, a pandas timestamp, or a string.  I have opted to demonstrate producing a string.

Okay now for a solution:

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser, relativedelta  
from dateutil.utils import default_tzinfo
def gen_date(stDate: str, ofst: int) -> str:
    std = parser.parse(stDate + ' 00:00 UTC') #Makes TZ aware timestamp
    newdt = std + relativedelta.relativedelta(hours=ofst)
    return newdt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y:%H %Z") #Returns TZ aware string
    
offset_lst = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60,66,72,78,84,90,96,102,108,114,120,126]
std = '28-04-2019'
for ofst in offset_lst:
    print(f"Start Date {std} + Offset {ofst} hours -> {gen_date(std, ofst)}")
```

The above yields:

```
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 0 hours -> 04-28-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 6 hours -> 04-28-2019:06 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 12 hours -> 04-28-2019:12 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 18 hours -> 04-28-2019:18 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 24 hours -> 04-29-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 30 hours -> 04-29-2019:06 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 36 hours -> 04-29-2019:12 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 42 hours -> 04-29-2019:18 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 48 hours -> 04-30-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 54 hours -> 04-30-2019:06 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 60 hours -> 04-30-2019:12 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 66 hours -> 04-30-2019:18 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 72 hours -> 05-01-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 78 hours -> 05-01-2019:06 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 84 hours -> 05-01-2019:12 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 90 hours -> 05-01-2019:18 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 96 hours -> 05-02-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 102 hours -> 05-02-2019:06 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 108 hours -> 05-02-2019:12 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 114 hours -> 05-02-2019:18 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 120 hours -> 05-03-2019:00 UTC
Start Date 28-04-2019 + Offset 126 hours -> 05-03-2019:06 UTC
```

Comment: I thought UTC times ended with a Z, otherwise the timezone is unspecified and could be anywhen?

Comment: @barny The data provided was not time zone specific, so the solution provided is also non time zone specific.

Comment: @barny I have updated the solution to incorporate UTC Timezone awareness.  ;-)

Comment: I will keep in mind the points suggested by you while uploading a question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If my solution answers your question, please indicate the question answered